# How to find MDK MAC (EMV)?

Tags: apdu, emv

I work on EMV since a while, I develop an application to pass specific emv apdu commands. It's already OK for some commands like select application, generate application cryptogram... The problem concern apdu who need Message Authentication Code, more precisely the master derivation key. My question is in three parts but, feel free to answer one that inspires you :

Can I calculate, derivate or find the MDK by any way ? Which one ?
Is that MDK MAC the same as MDK AC ? If yes, can I find MDK AC from an ARQC or TC ?
Any other advice for MACing ?

PS : I'm not a native English speaker, please be indulgent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All information about key and key managment you could find in [Book 2 - Security and Key Management](https://www.emvco.com/specifications.aspx?id=223).

MDK - from Visa terminology Master Derivation Key. MasterCard calls them differently. Master Derivation Key - key which is stored in issuer bank hsm. From this MDK key and card PAN number hsm derives card master keys unique for each card. Unique card master keys consists of 3 main (or some times 4) keys: AC, MAC, DEC. This keys are stored on card. From each key card derives session key for each operation, so all session keys will be unique to.

> Can I calculate, derivate or find the MDK by any way ? Which one ?

No chance. Only for test cards, if you will independently personolise you own card with your own MDK key, for personal uses/experiments.

> Is that MDK MAC the same as MDK AC ?

Different

> If yes, can I find MDK AC from an ARQC or TC ?

No chance

Comment: Thank you for your very complete answer Alexander Vgn

Comment: @Alexander HSM does not store any keys other than its LMK key pairs.
When it comes to MDK, you Generate clear component(s) and then Form the actual key, which is then stored in any system which uses it.
For eg. during authorization you send CDOL1 elements + MDK/LMK. 
The generated components are stored securely by the bank.

Comment: @AdarshNanu, just to correct something for anybody looking at this post. Some HSM do store keys on their memory indeed and some don't. IAs an example LUNA HSMs have internal slots to store keys (ithers than LMKs). The limit is the internal memory of the HSM. You can also have external vaults with this HSM as you described.

Comment: @wrbp yes I agree